# Can we make an HTTP call from a smart contract in Solana blockchain?

Tags: api, rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, solana

I was not able to find anyone invoking this subject, which means that it probably is not feasible, but I need to make sure.

So is there any way one could call some endpoint from a smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not, by protocol. Accepting such thing would be a hole security. Smart contracts are meant to deal with data on the blockchain itself in an isolated and controlled environment.

**Disclaimer**: this is not only for solana but for most blockchains (cannot say for sure if for all of them, but it would make sense it would).

Comment: Hey. If you haven't already done so, please commit to the Solana Stackexchange. area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126615/solana You could greatly help us reach our goal!

Answer (score 1):

No. calling external links on chain, requires oracle services such as [Chainlink](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data/)

which doesn't seem to be available on solana, as of now.

Answer (score 0):

chainlink data feeds are available on solana.

```
 https://docs.chain.link/docs/solana/data-feeds-solana/
```

Blockchains are deterministic, that means If I take whole history of transactions which are stored on nodes, and go through them I should get the same state.

> The result of any transaction must always be the same for nodes to
> verify it no matter where, how and when we call it

In smart contract, oracle services are used. [What is blockcahin Oracle](https://chain.link/education/blockchain-oracles#:%7E:text=Blockchain%20oracles%20are%20entities%20that,legacy%20systems%2C%20and%20advanced%20computations.):

> Blockchain oracles are entities that connect blockchains to external
> systems, thereby enabling smart contracts to execute based upon inputs
> and outputs from the real world. Oracles provide a way for the
> decentralized Web 3.0 ecosystem to access existing data sources,
> legacy systems, and advanced computations.

Comment: Hey. If you haven't already done so, please commit to the Solana Stackexchange. area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126615/solana You could greatly help us reach our goal!